# Reflection Class Properties

Tags: vb.net, class, reflection

I have a class and I'm trying to loop through all the objects in the class.

The code below always has a count of `0`, is there something I'm missing?

```
Public Class SomeClass
    Public Value1 As String
    Public Value2 As String
    Public Value3 As String
    Public Value4 As String
End Class

Public Function FindClassValue() As Boolean
    Dim someobj As New SomeClass
    Dim myType As Type = someobj.GetType
    Dim properties As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo() = myType.GetProperties()
    For Each p As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo In properties
        Debug.WriteLine(p.Name)
    Next
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

`Value1` to `Value4` are not declared as properties, but as variables.
Declare them like this:

```
Public Class SomeClass
    Public Property Value1 As String
    Public Property Value2 As String
    Public Property Value3 As String
    Public Property Value4 As String
End Class
```

**See also:** [Difference Between Properties and Variables in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/differences-between-properties-and-variables)

Comment: Not criticizing your answer, just some info you may want to include to make it more complete.  The documentation may call them variables (like normal people would), but in Reflection parlance the term is Field.  If the OP wants to retrieve them, then [Type.GetFields](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ch9714z3(v=vs.110).aspx) should be used to retrieve a array of FieldInfo objects.